# Solving recurrence relations where they cannot be easily put in MT form

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, recurrence

I have the following recurrence relation:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n
```

In this instance, I believe the solution is found by:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n = 2T(n/2) + n
```

Here, the Master Theorem can be applied:

```
 a = b = 2, f(n) = n
 n^(log2(2)) vs n --> n vs n
```

Thus, the solution would be:

```
 Theta(n log n)
```

How would I find the solution for the following situations:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + n
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + n^2
```

Those don't look like they can be easily put into MT form, so I am not quite sure what to do.

Comment: You could possibly say that `T(n/2)>=T(n/4)` hence we have that if `A(n) = 2A(n/2)` and `B(n) =2B(n/4)` then `A(n) >= T(n) >= B(n)` and since both A, B are O(nlog n)  then T must also be. Though there ought to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Those are of a form that can be handled by Akra--Bazzi: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

Answer (score 0):

Since T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + n satisfies the criteria of Akra-Bazzi method[see CRLS, pages 112 - 113 ], than you can use that method to solve the recurrence.

To solve the recurrence, we first need to find the unique real number p such that

(1/2)^p + (1/4)^p = 1

<=> (1/2)^p + (1/2^2)^p = 1

<=> (1/2)^p + (1/2)^2p = 1

<=> (1/2)^p * [1 + (1/2)^p] = 1

Let x = (1/2)^p, then we have an equation of the following form

x * (1 + x) = 1

<=> x + x^2 = 1

<=> x^2 + x - 1 = 0

=> x = (-1 + sqrt(5)) / 2 -> x = 1

=> (1/2)^p = 1

<=> (1/2)^p = (1/2)^0

<=> p = 0

The solution to the recurrence is then

T(n) = (x^p * (1 + integral-from-1-to-n-(u/u^(p+1))du))

<=> T(n) = (x^0 * (1 + integral-from-1-to-n-(u/u^(0+1))du))

<=> T(n) = (1 * (1 + integral-from-1-to-n-(1)du))

<=> T(n) = (1 * (1 + (n - 1)))

<=> T(n) = (1 * (n))

<=> T(n) = (n)

The same way can you solve T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + n^2